# How can I force Caliburn.Micro.Xamarin.Forms to use a specific version of Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: nuget, caliburn.micro, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to add the Caliburn.Micro 3.0alpha NuGet package to an existing Xamarin.Forms project. I first seems adding the package via NuGet is successful, but at the end it rolls back, and I get the error message that a newer package of Xamarin.Forms is already installed. 
How can I force Caliburn.Micro to ignore this error and use the installed version of Xamarin.Forms ?

My NuGet output :

```
PM>  Install-Package Caliburn.Micro.Xamarin.Forms -Pre
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Caliburn.Micro.Core (= 3.0.0-alpha)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Xamarin.Forms (= 1.4.2.6355)'.
Installing 'Caliburn.Micro.Core 3.0.0-alpha'.
Successfully installed 'Caliburn.Micro.Core 3.0.0-alpha'.
Installing 'Xamarin.Forms 1.4.2.6355'.
Successfully installed 'Xamarin.Forms 1.4.2.6355'.
Installing 'Caliburn.Micro.Xamarin.Forms 3.0.0-alpha'.
Successfully installed 'Caliburn.Micro.Xamarin.Forms 3.0.0-alpha'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Already referencing a newer version of 'Xamarin.Forms'.At line:1 char:2
+  Install-Package Caliburn.Micro.Xamarin.Forms -Pre
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot force Caliburn.Micro.Core 3.0.0-alpha to use any other version of Xamarin.Forms other than 1.4.2.6355.

The Caliburn.Micro.Core 3.0.0-alpha NuGet package has a dependency which restricts to a single Xamarin.Forms version.

```
<dependency id="Xamarin.Forms" version="[1.4.2.6355]" />
```

The only workarounds are:

1. Modify the Caliburn.Micro.Core NuGet package to relax the dependency.
2. Do not use NuGet.

Caliburn.Micro.Core might not work with a different version of Xamarin.Forms even if the above workarounds are tried.